# Function pointer syntax

Tags: c++, function-pointers, typedef

I encountered two different codes using function pointers.

Please tell me which one is better? Is there any preference?

```
typedef int myFunction(int a,int b);
extern myFunction *ptfunction;
```

and

```
typedef int (*ptfunction)(int a,int b);
```

Comment: I'd go with the first seeing as the second won't compile.

Comment: I don't really understand the need of typedef here. Wouldn't simply declaring int (*ptfunction)(int a,int b); achieve the same as the typedef? And I consider the simple declaration to be more clear. (And in case you don't need it, the compiler will optimize it away anyways...)

Comment: It would be helpful if you edited your original post and added two working examples.

Answer (score 5):

Both are bad, in that they are syntactically incorrect.

You need:

```
typedef int (*myFunction)(int a, int *b);
```

Comment: The first is fine (syntactically at least) - you can define a function type, you just can't declare objects of that type.

Answer (score 1):

Neither, use `std::function`

```
std::function<int (int ,int)> ptfunction;
ptfunction = f1;
```

Example (it's in std in c++0x):

**[how to use boost bind](http://www.radmangames.com/programming/how-to-use-boost-bind)**

**[std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)**

Comment: I like the suggestion of using `std:::function` instead, but there's no need for `std::bind` in there at all. You can just do `ptfunction = f1;`

Comment: Well i wasn't really sure you could do that without the bind.

Comment: You only need bind if you want to do more complex things rather than just forward.

Answer (score 1):

The second is invalid; it would be equivalent to the first if you fix the first line to declare a variable, not a type:

```
int (*ptfunction)(int a, int b);
```

Which is "better" depends entirely on what you want to do with these things. If you need to refer to the same type many times, then the `typedef` will make things clearer; if you simply want to declare a single function pointer as in your examples, then it just adds extra noise.

(Presumably, in your first example, the second parameter should be `int` not `int*`, otherwise the function call wouldn't compile).

It's often more convenient and flexible to use function objects, and `std::function` in particular, since these can have arbitrary state bound to them. But that's beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

The first one contains another error: You cannot cast int to a pointer to int. And which one is better? They are both completely out of context.

Answer (score 0):

for the 1st code, you have to define ptfunction somewhere.
and i don't think 2nd code can be compiled.

try this:

```
typedef int *PTFUNCTION(int, int);
PTFUNCTION func = f1;
func(1, 2);
```